# Navigation using routing in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

Look at the following list -

1. auth
2. auth/login
3. auth/forget-password
4. dashboard
5. dashboard/cart
6. dashboard/delivery
7. dashboard/users

auth has a common backgound for login and forget-passowrd.

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module')
      .then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },

  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module').then(m => m.AdminDashboardModule)
  },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/auth/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/auth/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

and dashboard looks like this...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: DashboardMainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardBodyComponent },
      { path: '', loadChildren: ()=> import('./dashboard-common/dashboard-common.module').then(m=>m.DashboardCommonModule)}]
   // loading dashboard-common which is the common part of cart, delivery and user component

  }
];
```

There are some cards in dashboard body component with names cart, delivery and users.
dashboard-header has nav bar which will be common in every page. it is loading in dashboard-main in  selector tag and dashboard-body is loading in  inside dashboard-main also. Now i want to connect cart and delivery with dashboard. I can make cart and delivery the child components of in dashboard by routing using children array but the thing is cart, users and delivery page has a common part like this....

```
----------------- NAV BAR ------------- (inside dashboard-main-component)

<-back                              + add   (common part
-------*cart------delivery-----users------- (common part)
----------------Body-content----------------
```

i can do make it load like this...
dashboard/common/cart
I can also include the common part in all three pages (repetition)
I can also try making cart users and delivery as separate modules and lazy load them inside dashboard as children.

Any suggestions ? If you want more information then reply me

Comment: which comman part you are talking about, back and add ?

Comment: yes, back, add and cart-delivery-users nav header